# Using a mapped drive as a variable

Tags: powershell, variables, mapping

We're looking at swapping a file server with a newer one. The new one will have a new IP and name.

My aim is to remove the mapped drive our users have for the current server and replace it with a new one. The problem is our users have it on different letters. So I need to run a script that will replace the UNC path regardless of drive letter.

My script so far can find me the drive letter, but it's not removing the mapping.

--

```
Get-PSDrive | ForEach {

If ( $_.DisplayRoot -eq '\\OLDSERVER\PATH' ) {


Remove-PSDrive -Name $_.Name

New-PSDrive –Name $_.Name –PSProvider FileSystem –Root "\\NEWSERVER\PATH" –Persist


   }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error when attempting to remove the mapping or is it just procedding and then erroring out when you try to create the new drive?  Also I know it may be more work in the short term but from a process perspective would now be a good time to standardize the drive letters?  I'll bet your help desk would thank you.

Comment: Might be a good time to look into using [Group Policy Preferences to map drives based on group membership](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/01/07/using-group-policy-preferences-to-map-drives-based-on-group-membership/), you'll only ever have to change the drive paths in one single place next time.

Comment: Have you tried remove-psdrive -force?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell cannot remove a mapping it didnt put in. I've changed it to a net-use command and it works.

Comment: PSDrives are not the same as mapped network drives. `net use` does work as we'll as `wscript.network`. Pretty sure there's a WMI variant as well.